# appium inspector not running on mac

Tags: ios, appium

I have appium version 1.4 with xcode 6.2 and ios 8.4.1 . I run appium doctor and everything is fine for ios platform. On running inspector it throws this error:

> Could not start new session, app path required

I have given app path also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mac El Capitan (Ver 10.11.1), Xcode 7.0.1(7B91b), Appium 1.4.13**

**iPhone 5 (iOS 7.0.4) - OK**

i. In Xcode, make sure the Debug Code Signing Identity in Build Settings->Code Signing is set to **Developer** provisioning  profile.

ii. Build and run (⌘R) the app directly to the real device from Xcode. After that stop the running.

iii.  Build the app (⌘B) so it will generate the .app file.

iv. In Appium->iOS Settings, point the App Path to the app located in **Debug-iphonesimulator**. Set the **Force Device**, **Platform Version**  , and **UDID**.

v. In Appium, click Launch and then Inspector.

**For iPhone with iOS 8 and above - OK**

i. In your iPhone device, Go to **Settings -> Developer**, Enable the **UI Automation**.

ii. Same steps as iPhone 5 (iOS 7.0.4)  starting from i to v.

**iPhone 6 (iOS 8.4.1) - OK**

**iPhone 6 Plus (iOS 9.0.2) - OK**

**iPhone 6 (iOS 9.1) - OK**

**iPad Mini 2 (iOS 7.1.2) -  OK**

**iPad Air (iOS 9.0.2) - OK**

**For simulator - OK**

For testing by using simulator, in **Appium-> Developer Settings**, check **Custom Server Flags** and insert **--native-instruments-lib**.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try/check:

1. If you are using a device, try clearing device logs using xcode.
2. Check if device is in provisioning profile.
3. Check if the platform version (eg: 8.1, 8.2, etc) you are providing is correct.

Comment: Device is in provisioning profile and platform version is correct as well. Logs I will try but I doubt that logs will impact launching the inspector

Comment: Clearing log does impacts appium session, since the log capture does not starts in time. https://discuss.appium.io/t/log-capture-did-not-start-in-a-reasonable-amount-of-time/1204