# Appium Inspector launches but shows no UI contents on the screen for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, appium-ios

I have installed appium Version 1.4.13 (Draco).

In the appium iOS configuration provided the following details

a. app path /Users/mac/Documents/testing/automationTesting.app
b. Force device iphone6, 
3. platform version 8.2
4. unchecked the UDID and bundle ID. The .app was generated using Xcode ver 7.0.1

After launching the appium and getting the response code 200, i tried to launch the inspector and it gets launched successfully.

I see the below debug info on the appium console
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.036 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}

Where as no images are getting loaded in the inspector and also the iOS simulator which was running before gets disappeared.

I have also looked into the below stack over flow urls and ensured that the steps are followed

[Appium Inspector not able to load image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820222/appium-inspector-not-able-to-load-image)

[appium inspector not running on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337247/appium-inspector-not-running-on-mac)

Any inputs/suggestions would be of help

Comment: i solved this by using xcode 7.2 just install newly with appium draco.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Instead of simulator i tried to configure the appium to run on the device by providing the UDID and bundle ID. I was able to launch the inspector successfully and get the UI elements values required for automation.

Option 2: I had upgraded the xcode to the latest version and it started launching the inspector in the simulator mode itself.